# Create Grouped TableViewCell from xib

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm trying to create a custom tableviewcell with interface builder. The problem is I can't seem to find a setting to make the cell a grouped cell instead of the normal plain cell.

The problem comes when the interface loads the contents (textfield,label,etc.) go beyond the edge of the grouped cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the cell subviews autoresizing mask.

Comment: I removed the constraints (new feature for ios 6 only) and now it works fine... weird :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the new constraints feature by going to the table view cell in interface builder and selecting the little page icon (file info) and unchecking "Use Autolayout"